# can we reset concurrency at run time for rabbit:listener-container in spring?

Tags: spring-amqp

I have the following configuration in xml configuration of spring.

```
 <rabbit:listener-container id="testListenerContainer" connection-factory="connectionFactory" prefetch="1" concurrency="10">
        <rabbit:listener ref="testListener" queues="${testInputQueueName}" />
    </rabbit:listener-container>
```

If I want to decrease the concurrency, is it possible to manually change concurrency, let spring reload the configuration so that it could reduce the  concurrency? If possible, how to do that？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that at runtime. See `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` `setConcurrentConsumers` and `setMaxConcurrentConsumers`. Adn yes, the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` changes its internal state around a set of running `BlockingQueueConsumer`.

Only you need is the `id` of that `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` to inject it to your control service. in your case it is `testListenerContainer`.